# UnityEditor.EditorApplication' does not contain a definition for `ExitPlaymode'

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
For some reason I cannot use ExitPlaymode(), even IntelliSense cannot find the method. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.ExitPlaymode.html

Does anyone know what I can try to fix this? Much appreciated.

Things I have tried:

- Deleting the Library folder
- Setting the Project Settings > Player > Scripting Runtime Version to 4.x, and 3.5x, both didn't work.
- An alternative way to achieve the same effect is to use EditorApplication.isPlaying = false, but I want to find out why EditorApplication.ExitPlayMode() isn't working in the first place.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Omg you are a God. Please reply with an answer so I can accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EditorApplication.ExitPlaymode` was added in Unity 2019. It won't be there if you're using 2018.x or earlier.

Pro tip: this is mentioned when looking at the version drop-down in the docs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You being able to still change between Runtime Version 4.x and 3.5 hints that you are using an older version of Unity.

Just for completeness and in addition to [kmdreko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017117/7111561)

In older versions before [`EditorApplication.ExitPlayMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.ExitPlaymode.html) was introduced or - as the API states - as alternative you simply would set [`EditorApplication.isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isPlaying.html)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
    Application.Quit();
#endif
```